# How to keep multiple select in sync onChange using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, listbox, onchange

I'm trying to figure out how to keep in sync two or more selects. I actually created several select elements (I'm not sure if this is the most accurate approach, if there's another way I'd be grateful if someone tells me).

If I select `North America` in the first one, only the select with `id="north"` will show automatically and the others will remain hidden, if I change to `Central America`, the rest will change as well, showing only the select with `id="central"` and the rest hidden.

This is what I got so far:

```
<select id="continent">
    <option value="1">North America</option>
    <option value="2">Central America</option>
    <option value="3">South America</option>
</select>

<select id="north">
    <option value="1">Canada</option>
    <option value="2">USA</option>
    <option value="3">Mexico</option>
</select>

<select id="central">
    <option value="1">Guatemala</option>
    <option value="2">Costa Rica</option>
    <option value="3">Nicaragua</option>
</select>

<select id="south">
    <option value="1">Brazil</option>
    <option value="2">Argentina</option>
    <option value="3">Chile</option>
</select>
```

So far I've only got to sync two selects with same value:

```
$("#continent").change(function(){
    $("#north").val($("#continent").val())
});
```

However, this is far from what I need. Could anyone help me figure out the correct approach?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you use an `if` statement to decide which `<select>` to show or hide?

Comment: Yes that might be also an option, I was looking for approaches to solve it, but since I needed the selects to show/hide after changing the first select, I didn't know how to tell them to change live.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to select text of `selected` option and get first part of it that is `id` of other `select`. Then hide all siblings of `select` and show `select` has specific id.

```js
$("#continent").change(function(){
    var id = $(this).find("option:selected").text().split(" ")[0].toLowerCase();
    $(this).siblings().hide().siblings("#"+id).show();
}).siblings().hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="continent">
    <option value="">Select one</option>
    <option value="1">North America</option>
    <option value="2">Central America</option>
    <option value="3">South America</option>
</select>
<select id="north">
    <option value="1">Canada</option>
    <option value="2">USA</option>
    <option value="3">Mexico</option>
</select>
<select id="central">
    <option value="1">Guatemala</option>
    <option value="2">Costa Rica</option>
    <option value="3">Nicaragua</option>
</select>
<select id="south">
    <option value="1">Brazil</option>
    <option value="2">Argentina</option>
    <option value="3">Chile</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Your solution worked like a charm! It's a very nice approach! Thank you very much sir!

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this if it doesn't bother you much to use some different ids:

First change the ids of the other selects.

```
<select id="continent">
    <option value="1">North America</option>
    <option value="2">Central America</option>
    <option value="3">South America</option>
</select>

<select id="group-1" class="country-group">
    <option value="1">Canada</option>
    <option value="2">USA</option>
    <option value="3">Mexico</option>
</select>

<select id="group-2" class="country-group">
    <option value="1">Guatemala</option>
    <option value="2">Costa Rica</option>
    <option value="3">Nicaragua</option>
</select>

<select id="group-3" class="country-group">
    <option value="1">Brazil</option>
    <option value="2">Argentina</option>
    <option value="3">Chile</option>
</select>
```

Then hide all the selects, and only show the one related to the continent you want.

```
$("#continent").change(function(){
  $(".country-group").val()).hide();
  $("#group-"+$("#continent").val()).show();
});
```

As an alternative, if you don't really need all to be in different selects, you can use something like [Option Groups](http://www.w3schools.com/Tags/tag_optgroup.asp). It's supported by all browsers according to w3schools.

```
<select>
  <optgroup label="North America">
    <option value="1">Canada</option>
    <option value="2">USA</option>
    <option value="3">Mexico</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Central America">
    <option value="1">Guatemala</option>
    <option value="2">Costa Rica</option>
    <option value="3">Nicaragua</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="South America">
    <option value="1">Brazil</option>
    <option value="2">Argentina</option>
    <option value="3">Chile</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Or if you wanted to work with prettier/handier JS libraries that add extra fucntionality, you could take a look at [Select2](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#single), [Chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/#optgroup-support) or [Selectize's Option Groups](http://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/)

Comment: Hadn't looked at the Option Groups, that might be a great alternative. I'll take a look at the libraries you mention as well. Thank you for your answer!